# Is there a method to check if two arrays contain same element in any order and check if same element is obtained with same index in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
arr = [1,4,6,3]
arr2 = [3,4,3,6]

arr.each do |item|
 p "X" if arr2.include?(item)
end
```

but the above only returns X if the element is found but I want it to return "O" when both array contain same element in the same index and I don't want the X to repeat if there is more than one element found.

I tried using `each`*`with`*`index` but couldn't get the result

Comment: *I don't want the X to repeat if there is more than one element found* — what do you want for this case? It's better to update your question for expected output

Comment: Are you trying to implement Mastermind?

Comment: Are we to assume that `arr` and `arr2` are the same size? Is efficiency important? (If you are coding a board game the answer would probably be "no".)

Comment: Suppose you had a method `def m(arr, arr2); arr.each { |item| p "X" if arr2.include?(item) }; end`. How are you going to perform a unit test of that method? You cannot. That's one reason you should pull statements that display results outside of the method: `def m(arr, arr2); arr.any? { |item| arr2.include?(item) }; end`. Then `p "X" if m(arr, arr2)`. (True, the two versions of the method are not the same, but the reader should get the idea.)

Comment: Three unanswered questions so far. If you want our help you need to do your part: answer the questions!

Comment: You could first calculate the intersection of both array, which gives you a list of common elements. Then you loop over this list and calculate the respective position in each array.  If the positions are the same, you have found a candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the logic into a class with a few helper methods:

```
class CodeBreaker
  def initialize(guess, code)
    @guess = guess
    @code = code
    @numbers = Set.new(code)

    return if guess.size == code.size

    raise ArgumentError, 'guess and code need to share the same size'
  end

  def hint 
    guess.map.with_index do |number, index|
      mark_when_equal_at_index(index) || mark_when_number_in_code(number) || '-'
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :guess, :code, :numbers

  def mark_when_equal_at_index(index)
    'O' if guess[index] == code[index]
  end

  def mark_when_number_in_code(number)
    'X' if code.include?(number)
  end
end

code_breaker = CodeBreaker.new([1, 4, 6, 3], [3, 4, 3, 6])
code_breaker.hint
#=> ["-", "O", "X", "X"]
```

Comment: Note that a guess of `[1, 1, 1, 1]` with a code of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` will report four `X`s although there's only one `1` in the code.

Comment: @Stefan For your example, it would return `["O", "X", "X", "X"]`. I would consider that correct unless each number can only be used once or the number of `'X'` should be similar to the number of occurrences in the code. I am not sure about Mastermind game's rules about this.

Comment: Of course, I missed that `O` :) I was assuming you wanted your code to resemble Mastermind (which would yield `["O", "-", "-", "-"]` because there are no more `1`s in the code). In the context of the question (as it is currently written) it seems perfectly fine.

Comment: ^ An example solution for Mastermind: https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/0d56e32d142c34570c68c2c8cb8edc36 First checking for an exact match (value + position), then a loose match (value only), keeping track of the amount of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, 4, 6, 3]
arr2 = [3, 4, 3, 6]

arr.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if item == arr2[index]
    puts "O"
  elsif arr2.include? item
    puts "X"
  else
    puts 'element not found'
  end
end
```

Result

```
element not found
O
X
X
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the code implements a board game, in which case efficiency is unimportant. The emphasis should instead be on readability and ease of testing.

I assume the two arrays are the same size, as in the example.

```
def equal_at_same_index?(arr1, arr2)
  arr1.zip(arr2).any? { |e1,e2| e1 == e2 }
end
```

```
def equal_at_different_indices?(arr1, arr2)
  arr1.any? { |e1| arr2.include?(e1) }
end
```

```
def equal_result(arr1, arr2)
  if equal_at_same_index?(arr1, arr2)
    'O'
  elsif equal_at_different_indices?(arr1, arr2)
    'X'
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Try it.

```
equal_result([1,2,3,4], [5,6,3,7])
  #=> "O"
equal_result([1,2,3,4], [5,3,7,8])
  #=> "X"
equal_result([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
  #=> nil
```

The return value of `equal_result`, if not `nil`, can then be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you want.  It uses [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to check two arrays to see if there is any case were the same element value is present at the same index.

```
arr = [1, 4, 6, 3]
arr2 = [3, 4, 3, 6]

result = false
arr.zip(arr2) { |a, b| result = true if a == b }
puts result
```

Comment: Or just: `result = arr.zip(arr2).any? { |a, b| a == b |`

Answer (score 0):

My first answer assumed you just wanted the cases were the same element appeared at the same index. I am adding a second answer the provides both the 'X' and 'O'.

In all but the first example I incorporated `any?` along with `zip` (as Cary showed - its better then changing a variable inside the zip block).
I think [Array#intersect?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-intersect-3F) gets what you want for the 'O' cases.

In all examples below you get `'O'` for ref_ary vs ary1, `'X'` for ref_ary ary2 and `nil` for ref_ary vs ary3

```
ref_ary  = [1, 4, 6,  3]
ary1     = [3, 4, 3,  6]
ary2     = [3, 5, 3,  6]
ary3     = [7, 8, 9, 10]


# original answer but includes the 'O' part as well
def analyze(ref_ary, ary)
  result = nil
  ref_ary.zip(ary) { |a, b| result = 'O' if a == b }
  result || 'X' if ref_ary.intersect?(ary)
end

puts "ref vs ary1 = #{analyze(ref_ary, ary1)}"
puts "ref vs ary2 = #{analyze(ref_ary, ary2)}"
puts "ref vs ary3 = #{analyze(ref_ary, ary3)}"

# using `any?` you don't have to set result in the block.
def analyze2(ref_ary, ary)
  result = 'O' if ref_ary.zip(ary).any? { |a, b| a == b }
  result || 'X' if ref_ary.intersect?(ary)
end

puts "ref vs ary1 = #{analyze2(ref_ary, ary1)}"
puts "ref vs ary2 = #{analyze2(ref_ary, ary2)}"
puts "ref vs ary3 = #{analyze2(ref_ary, ary3)}"

# eliminates the intermediate variable `result`
def analyze3(ref_ary, ary)
  if ref_ary.zip(ary).any? { |a, b| a == b }
    'O'
  elsif ref_ary.intersect?(ary)
    'X'
  end
end

puts "ref vs ary1 = #{analyze3(ref_ary, ary1)}"
puts "ref vs ary2 = #{analyze3(ref_ary, ary2)}"
puts "ref vs ary3 = #{analyze3(ref_ary, ary3)}"
puts "ref vs ary3 = #{analyze3(ref_ary, ary3).class}"
```